# Plugin not found: jpa

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
        </args>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>spring</plugin>
            <plugin>jpa</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

when I run `mvn compile`, the result in the console prints an error:

> Plugin not found: jpa: java.util.NoSuchElementException

I have checked [the reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support)
but still cannot figure it out. Did anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 24):

Add the dependency below to your `<dependencies>` element:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

See also the official [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin)

A full plugin configuration would be something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
        </args>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>all-open</plugin>
            <plugin>spring</plugin>
            <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
            <plugin>jpa</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: To those coming from Google, make sure it's `<build><plugins><plugin>` (kotlin-maven-plugin) `<dependencies> <dependency>...` and not any other place

Answer (score -2):

solved by add lines below:

```
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
                    <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
```

the jpa plugin also need no-arg plugin exist

Comment: The real (and only necessary) solution is your first answer  (adding the dependency `kotlin-maven-noarg`). After that, you can use the `<compilerPlugins>` section from your question.